# Refactoring js to append content within a div programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with replicating results in one piece of code within another. The purpose of the code is to add a popover to an arbitrary link that contains cascading dropdowns. My code is well commented and within the document.ready, you can see where I add content to the popover, and where I call the recursive function to add the subMenus.

The working version of this code is at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/arockwell/k5z3e5e8/12/) and it's heavily dependant on this type of structure within the html:

```
<div id="popover-markup"> <a href="#" class="trigger">Popover link</a>
  <!-- contents of popover -->
  <div class="content hide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Although, I want to refactor my code so that it would only be dependant on:

```
<div id="popover-markup"> <a href="#" class="trigger">Popover link</a>
</div>
```

In [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/arockwell/418ojd64/1/), I have tried to do that, but ran into issues with my recursive function no longer recognizing it's second parameter, resulting in empty submenus. My main changes are that within the document.ready, I no longer append to a static ".content" but to:

```
var base = $(`<div class="content hide">`);
```

Then ending up with returning base. Please let me know what I can do to fix the sub menus or if there's a better way to go about this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) Why are you refactoring, out of curiosity? In what area does the current code not meet your expectations? 2) Is your menu dynamically populated? Or can you put the text into the HTML and be fine?

Comment: 1) I would like to see if it's possible to get it to work without the content div, and right now, if you try to click one of the links within the popover, all of the submenus arent working like they do in the original link. 2) it is populated dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Well, the core issue here is that you're using non-unique id's. In the screenshot `menu1` is an id you're using in multiple places.

[image]

You're also basically creating the DOM in two places, which I don't understand. What if you have 10 of these popovers? Will you generate another 10 hidden clones in the DOM? What you should be doing is just populating your actual `.popover` once. Parse the structure and build one popover.